on notation of subscribt of translational invariance of measure
let $m$ be an elementary measure defined by the following $m(S):=\lim _{N\rightarrow + \infty} \frac{1}{N} \text{card}{(S\cap\frac{Z}{N})} $.
if we have m[0,1), i know we can divide it into a finite union of disjoint intervals of equal length
so m[0,1)= $\bigcup$[$\frac{k_i}{N}$,$\frac{{k_{i+1}}}{N}$) where $0\le k_i<N$ where $k_i \in \mathbb{N} $
my question is about translational invariance
so we write $\bigcup_{0\le i<N}$[$\frac{k_i}{N}$,$\frac{{k_{i+1}}}{N}$)= $\bigcup$$[0,1)$+$\frac{k_i}{N}$ or is it +$\frac{k}{N}$ ?
because translational invariance is about translating with a constant but the subscript of i confuses me
is writing it +$\frac{k_i}{N}$ mean the translational invariance of each interval and is a shorthand form with a subscript in the union $\bigcup_{0\le i<N}$to make it clear?
is the equal length of the disjoint sets according to defined measure or naïve measure of (b-a) for interval(a,b)? the reason i ask this is whether this will effect the subscript of the constant of translation?
thank you for any help

In m:=$\lim x\rightarrow + \infty \frac{1}{N} \mathbf{card}{(S\cap\frac{Z}{N})} $, what is $x$? Did you mean $N\rightarrow + \infty$?

@Ramiro yes sorry i meant N i need to fix it. thank you for pointing it out

Think about it: if you want an arbitrary interval $[a,b)$ to be a translate of $[0,1),.$ What conditions must $a,b$ satisfy? In your case $a,b\in\mathbb N$ and presumably $b=a+1,.$ This holds for each interval $[k_i,k_{i+1}),.$ Do you see any problems still?

@KurtG. so  M{{0,1)}= M($[k_i,k_{i+1}),$ )=M{[0,1)+$k_i$} for each $k_i \in (\mathbb N)$ ? since $k_{i+1}$-$k_i$=1 and thus in my question it  is $\frac{k_i}{N}$. thank you for helping me be a little less confused

If $I$ is the empty interval, then
$$\lim_{N \to +\infty} \frac{1}{N} \mathbf{card}(I \cap \frac{Z}N)= 0  $$
If $I$ is a non-empty interval, and $a=\inf I$ and $b = \sup I$, then
$$\lim_{N \to +\infty} \frac{1}{N} \mathbf{card}(I \cap \frac{Z}N)= \lim_{N \to +\infty} \frac{1}{N} \frac{b-a}{\frac{1}{N}} = b-a$$
(continue)

Now, any translation of the empty interval is still the empty interval. Moreover, suppose $I$ is a non-empty interval and $a=\inf I$ and $b = \sup I$, then given any $t \in \Bbb R$, let $I+t$ be the translation of $I$ by $t$. We have  $a +t=\inf I+t$ and $b+t = \sup I+t$. It follows immediately that $$m(I+t)= (b+t) -(a+t) = b-a =m(I)$$
So $m$ is translation invariant on intervals.

@Ramiro thank you this was very helpful, you explained to me that the equality of lengths in this case would be the same if it was naive measure or elementary measure. but why is $\mathbf{card}(I \cap \frac{Z}N)$ =$ \frac {(b-a)}{\frac{1}{N}}$ according to the defined inf and sup. because this confuses me as it pertains to the measure

Try to explicitily calculate that $\lim_{N \to +\infty} \frac{1}{N} \mathbf{card}(I \cap \frac{Z}N)$ for $I=[a,b]$, $I=(a,b)$, $I=[a,b)$ and $I=(a,b]$.

@Ramiro alright ill try and see if i can understand this. there must be something I'm missing it has been a long day and my wits aren't with me. thank you for the help much appreciated

@Ramiro sorry i still don't quite understand it

You are asking why $$\lim_{N \to +\infty} \frac{1}{N}\mathbf{card}(I \cap \frac{Z}N)=\lim_{N \to +\infty} \frac{1}{N}\frac{b-a}{\frac{1}{N}} $$Proof: Note that
$$ \frac{b-a}{\frac{1}{N}}-1 \leqslant \mathbf{card}(I \cap \frac{Z}N) \leqslant \frac{b-a}{\frac{1}{N}}+1$$So$$ \frac{1}{N}\frac{b-a}{\frac{1}{N}} -\frac{1}{N} \leqslant \frac{1}{N}\mathbf{card}(I \cap \frac{Z}N) \leqslant \frac{1}{N}\frac{b-a}{\frac{1}{N}} +\frac{1}{N} $$So, by the Squeeze Theorem,$$\lim_{N \to +\infty} \frac{1}{N}\mathbf{card}(I \cap \frac{Z}N)=\lim_{N \to +\infty} \frac{1}{N}\frac{b-a}{\frac{1}{N}}$$

@Ramiro thank you this was very helpful although i should study more to see where $\frac{b-a}{\frac{1}{N}}-1 \leqslant \mathbf{card}(I \cap \frac{Z}N) \leqslant \frac{b-a}{\frac{1}{N}}+1$ came from im still slowly building my mathematical understanding. but thank you for taking the time to help me and answer my questions :)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
